# JavaScript Typed Arrays - Different Views

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a handle on the interaction between different types of typed arrays.

Example 1.

```
var buf = new ArrayBuffer(2);
var arr8 = new Int8Array(buf);
var arr8u = new Uint8Array(buf);

arr8[0] = 7.2;
arr8[1] = -45.3;

console.log(arr8[0]);       // 7
console.log(arr8[1]);       // -45
console.log(arr8u[0]);      // 7
console.log(arr8u[1]);      // 211
```

I have no problem with the first three readouts but where does 211 come from in the last. Does this have something to do with bit-shifting because of the minus sign.

Example 2

```
var buf = new ArrayBuffer(4);
var arr8 = new Int8Array(buf);
var arr32 = new Int32Array(buf);

for (var i = 0; i < buf.byteLength; i++){
    arr8[i] = i;
}

console.log(arr8);      // [0, 1, 2, 3]
console.log(arr32);     // [50462976]
```

So where does the 50462976 come from?

Answer (score 4):

**Example #1**

Examine positive 45 as a binary number:

```
> (45).toString(2)
"101101"
```

Binary values are negated using a [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement):

```
00101101 => 45 signed 8-bit value
11010011 => -45 signed 8-bit value
```

When we read we read `11010011` as an unsigned 8-bit value, it comes out to `211`:

```
> parseInt("11010011", 2);
211
```

**Example #2**

If you print `50462976` in base 2:

```
> (50462976).toString(2);
"11000000100000000100000000"
```

We can add leading zeros and rewrite this as:

```
00000011000000100000000100000000
```

And we can break it into octets:

```
00000011 00000010 00000001 00000000
```

This shows binary `3`, `2`, `1`, and `0`. The storage of 32-bit integers is big-endian. The 8-bit values 0 to 3 are read in order of increasing significance when constructing the 32-bit value.

Comment: @apsillers...this helped me too

Answer (score 2):

**First question.**

Signed 8bit integers range from -128 to 127. The positive part (0-127) maps to binary values from  `00000000` to `01111111`), and the other half (-128-1) from `10000000` to `11111111`.

If you omit the first bit, you can create a number by adding a 7bit number to a boundary. In your case, the binary representation is `11010011`. The first bit is `1`, this means the number will be negative. The last 7bits are `1010011`, that gives us value `83`. Add it to the boundary: `-128 + 83 = -45`. That’s it.

**Second question.**

32bit integers are represented by four bytes in memory. You are storing four 8bit integers in the buffer. When converted to an `Int32Array`, all those values are combined to form one value.

If this was decimal system, you could think of it as combining "1" and "2" gives "12". It’s similar in this case, except the multipliers are different. For the first value, it’s `2^24`. Then it’s `2^16`, then `2^8` and finally `2^0`. Let’s do the math:

```
2^24 * 3 + 2^16 * 2 + 2^8 * 1 + 2^0 * 0 =
16777216 * 3 + 65536 * 2 + 256 * 1 + 1 * 0 =
50331648 + 131072 + 256 + 0 =
50462976
```

That’s why you’re seeing such a large number.

Comment: Thanks guys. Good explanations. I think I'll check out basic binary. Seems more to this than just 1 and 0.  :)