# JavaScript Typed Arrays - Different Views - 2

Tags: javascript

I posted a couple of questions on this a few days ago and got some excellent replies [JavaScript Typed Arrays - Different Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19692299/javascript-typed-arrays-different-views)

My second question involved two views, 8-bit array and 32-bit array of a buffer. By placing 0, 1, 2, 3, in the 8-bit I got 50462976 in the 32-bit. As mentioned the reason for the 32-bit value was well explained.

I can achieve the same thing with the following code:

```
var buf = new ArrayBuffer(4);
var arr8 = new Int8Array(buf);
var arr32 = new Int32Array(buf);

for (var x = 0; x < buf.byteLength; x++) {
    arr8[x] =
        (x << 24) |
        (x << 16) |
        (x <<  8) |
         x;
}

console.log(arr8);      // [0, 1, 2, 3]
console.log(arr32);     // [50462976]
```

I can't find anything that explains the mechanics of this process. It seems to be saying that each arr8 element equals X bit-shifted 24 positions OR bit-shifted 16 positions OR bit-shifted 8 positions OR not bit-shifted.

That doesn't really make sense to me. I'd appreciate it if someone could shed some light on this.
Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Basically, your buffer is like this:

```
00000000 00000001 00000010 00000011
```

When handled as an `Int8Array`, it reads each 8-bit group individually: 0, 1, 2, 3

When handled as an `Int32Array`, it reads 32-bit groups (ie. 4 8-bit groups) to get 50462976

Comment: I can understand how I get 50462976 from the 32-bit array. What I don't get is the "|" sign. Since it means OR how does that work in the above context. That's why I was asking for the "mechanics" of the process.

Comment: It's a bitwise OR. In this case, because x is less than 8, it's actually exactly the same as `+`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol this saved my life...Thanks for this answer

Answer (score 2):

The memory used by the buffer is interpreted as 8-bit bytes for the `Int8Array` and 32-bit words for the `Int32Array`.  The ordering of the bytes in the 8-bit array is the same as the ordering of the bytes in the single 32-bit word in the other array **because they're the same bytes**. There are no "mechanics" involved; it's just two ways of looking at the same 4 bytes of memory.

You get the exact same effect in C if you allocate a four-byte array and then create an `int` pointer to the same location.

Furthermore, this expression here:

```
arr8[x] =
    (x << 24) |
    (x << 16) |
    (x <<  8) |
     x;
```

will do precisely the same thing as

```
arr8[x] = x;
```

You're shifting the value of `x` up into ranges that will be truncated away when the value is actually saved into the (8-bit) array element.

Comment: +1 for explaining that the bits after the first 8 are truncated.